"Archer" episode: "Pam." "Pam!" "Pam." "Pam!"
I'm usually pretty good at remembering "Archer" episodes, but this one escapes me....
Sometime in Season 2 or 3, there's a scene in Malory's office where (Sterling) Archer is trying to get Pam to blab her gossipy mouth about something, and Malory is trying to get her to shut up, at the same time. Eventually Pam's compulsion to gossip gets the better of her, she spills the news to Archer in a burst, and runs from the office in terror.
The title is what Archer and Malory are saying to her, over and over again, instead of actually using persuasive tactics.

The episode Stage Two. The plot, from the Wiki, is:

When Malory suspects that she might have breast cancer, she undergoes
  a medical examination; Archer decides that he should be thoroughly
  checked for the disease as well.

From the script:

ARCHER: Mother. Pardon me, sorry, one second. Pam?
MALORY: No, you don't Pam!
ARCHER: Pam.
MALORY: Pam!
ARCHER: Pam.
PAM: I'm okay I'm okay, I'm good! I'm good
ARCHER: Pam.
PAM: Your mom's got breast cancer!
ARCHER: She what? !?
MALORY: Damn her piggy little eyes!


Thank you, and now I see how to Google it next time as well.

Not a problem, glad I could help. I'd never even heard of the show. You've inspired me to check out a few episodes!
